# element.style is increasing font size arbitrarily

Tags: css, emacs, org-mode

[This](http://stembase.space/test3.html) page was auto-generated by Emacs' org-mode HTML export. I've got it set up to use MathJax rendering of LaTeX symbols. On the third column of the *There Exists* line I've used inline LaTeX symbols surrounded by "$"

```
$\exists  x \mid x2>x$
```

which is proper LaTeX embedding, whereas the line above and below I haven't, i.e., Emacs just picks up LaTeX markup and inserts it without using "$". If you Inspect (I'm using Chrome) this code, you'll see it is throwing in a font-size increase for only this LaTeX markup, seemingly arbitrarily, making the symbols look abnormally large compared to the other symbols.

```
<span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 5.681em; height: 0px; font-size: 129%;">
```

How can I stop, block, override this `element.style` being inserted and blowing up my font size?

```
element.style {
￼    display: inline-block;
￼    position: relative;
￼    width: 5.713em;
￼    height: 0px;
￼    font-size: 129%;
}
```

**Update:**

I've narrowed the problem down to something in my custom stylesheet.css:

```
table {
    /* font-family: monospace; */
    font-family:'eulermedium_18';
    /* font-size: 1.05em; */
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:0.5em;
    margin-bottom:0.5em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

namely, the `font-family`. Above I've commented out `monospace`, which gave me a 129% arbitrary size. But then as you see I tried AMS Euler (ttf version converted by Font Squirrel, as is the Computer Modern) and it caused the `$...$` parts of the org-mode table in question to reduce the font size to 53%! Craziness. Again, with no `font-family` in `table` sizes are normal across LaTeX/MathJax and regular text. Is there any way to have the org-mode HTML export for MathJax stuff use my fonts correctly?

Comment: The `$...$` tirggers a MathJax interjection. The other two rows don't get that treatment. You could probably change a MathJax setting to change the size, but the fonts are different as well, so it is going to stick out unless you change that too. Why not treat them all the same? All `$...$` delimited or all without.

Comment: Yes, I will change to proper LaTeX enclosings, but that doesn't solve my problem. I guess I need to understand why the `element.style` thing is being called in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be related to `font-family` too. Column 3 of There Exists line seem to be use `font` as `STIXGeneral-Italic`, while the default `font` used at other places seem to be `monospace`. You can override these styles in your `stylesheet.css` using `!important` directive.

```
.mrow span{
    font-family: inherit!important;
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I've thrown `.mrow span {
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-size: 100%;
}

.org-left {
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-size: 100%;
}

.MathJax span {
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-size: 100%;
}

#MathJax-Span-1 {
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-size: 100%;
}` at this problem and nothing is working. Alas.

Comment: Funny, but when I rip out all headers and just have the naked table, MathJax is still the default, but the offending `element.style` section only increases the font to 104%. Will try to work backwards from this....

Comment: Unfortunately, I've narrowed it down to my custom stylesheet.css. Will weed through it to find what's causing this. Still, the `element.style` going from 129% down to 104% when I take out my stylesheet is odd.

Comment: Strange. When I do change on your site using local override, I can see the font-style and size change, more or less similar to font at other places.

Comment: By taking out the `font-family:monospace` from `table {
    /* font-family: monospace; */
 font-size: 1.05em; 
    margin-left:5%;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:0.5em;
    margin-bottom:0.5em;
    line-height: 1.5em; }` I get normal, un-messed-with font sizes. But with it in, it throws in the `element-style` font craziness.